# Find exponential creating function and compact formula on $b_n$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $b_n$ - number of ways to set $n$ different books at two distinguishable shelves, but on every shelf must be at least one book. Find exponential creating function and compact formula on $b_n$.

**My solution:**

$$(\frac{t}{1!}+\frac{t^2}{2!}+...)^2=(e^x-1)^2=e^{2x}-2e^x+1=\sum_{n \ge 0} 2^n \cdot \frac{x^n}{n!}-\sum_{n \ge 0} 2 \cdot \frac{x^n}{n!} +1=\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x^n}{n!} (2^n-2)$$
$$b_n=2^n-2$$
I checked this formula for $n=4$ but I haven't certain that this is a good solution.
Can you check it?

Comment: Do you mean exponential *generating* function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $2^n$ ways of setting $n$ books in two shelves. Substract $2$, which represents the two cases in which a shelf is empty. Then sum over all naturals and you get the series you wrote